# AssertionError: Assertion failed: length of coordinate array should match stride

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I was trying to create some polygons in my OpenLayers 3 map, but was getting the following error:

> AssertionError: Assertion failed: length of coordinate array should
>   match stride

The code I was using is as follows:

```
var geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon([
  [10.689697265625, -25.0927734375],
  [34.595947265625, -20.1708984375],
  [38.814697265625, -35.6396484375],
  [13.502197265625, -39.1552734375],
  [10.689697265625, -25.0927734375]
], "XY");

geometry.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    map: this.map,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [new ol.Feature({
            geometry: geometry
        })]
    })
});
```

I was struggling to find the solution, and could not find in the Internet any reference to the error itself (other than the source code of OpenLayers).

I have found the solution, but I am posting it here for reference, in case anyone stumbles into the same problem in the future.

So, what was it due?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much digging I have realised the definition of the polygon needed an extra set of brackets:

```
var geometry = new ol.geom.Polygon([ [
  [10.689697265625, -25.0927734375],
  [34.595947265625, -20.1708984375],
  [38.814697265625, -35.6396484375],
  [13.502197265625, -39.1552734375],
  [10.689697265625, -25.0927734375]
] ]);

geometry.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    map: this.map,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [new ol.Feature({
            geometry: geometry
        })]
    })
});
```

And this works!

This is the jsfiddle that has finally enlightened me: http://jsfiddle.net/q8s2z/111/

As the [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html) states, the *coordinates* parameter is an Array of Array of ol.Coordinate (which is also an array).

Likewise, a [MultiPolygon](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.0/apidoc/ol.geom.MultiPolygon.html) would be defined as:

```
var geometry = new ol.geom.MultiPolygon([ [
  [10.689697265625, -25.0927734375],
  [34.595947265625, -20.1708984375],
  [38.814697265625, -35.6396484375],
  [13.502197265625, -39.1552734375],
  [10.689697265625, -25.0927734375]
], [
  [10.689697265625, -25.0927734375],
  [34.595947265625, -20.1708984375],
  [38.814697265625, -35.6396484375],
  [13.502197265625, -39.1552734375],
  [10.689697265625, -25.0927734375]
] ]);
```